# Custom web part in a modal dialog pop-up

Tags: 2010, modal-dialog, custom-web-parts

Can we display a custom web part (developed in visual studio 2010) in a modal dialog pop-up? If yes then how can we do that... any tutorials or article?

Thanks!

Comment: As per below posters, yes you can. A WEbPart is nothing more than a ASCX (Server control). Put the custom web part on a page somewhere and open that page using the SharePont ModalDialog Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show any page using eg [SP.UI.ModalDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410259%28v=office.14%29.aspx). You could just add your WebPart to a page, and link to it:

```
<a title="aTitle" onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('http://link/to/page/with/webpart.aspx');return false;">
   aLink
</a>
```

Comment: Hey, that shouldn't be necessary. SP.UI.Dialog.$1h add ?IsDlg=1 , in fact it will add another if you have one in your url. Like this: ?IsDlg=1&IsDlg=1

Comment: Ah, true, ?IsDlg=1 is not needed in the URL.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can place web part in any page and show this page in dialog. How to call dialog: [MSDN: SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
 function OpenDialog(URL) {
  var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
  options.url = URL;
  options.width = 600;
  options.height = 400;
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
 }
 </script>
```